# Tabbar background disappear with scrollable SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

i got a probleme with my tabbar, the background disappear on differents views.

here is the code for the Tabbar :

```
struct CustomTabView: View {
@State var selection = 1

init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
}

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        Top50View()
            .tabItem {
                Text(Constantes.tab1)
                Image(systemName: Constantes.tab1Logo)
            }.tag(1)
        SearchView()
            .tabItem {
                Text(Constantes.tab2)
                Image(systemName: Constantes.tab2Logo)
            }.tag(2)
        MapView()
            .tabItem {
                Text(Constantes.tab3)
                Image(systemName: Constantes.tab3Logo)
            }.tag(3)
        ChatView()
            .tabItem {
                Text(Constantes.tab4)
                Image(systemName: Constantes.tab4Logo)
            }.tag(4)
        ProfilView()
            .tabItem {
                Text(Constantes.tab5)
                Image(systemName: Constantes.tab5Logo)
            }.tag(5)
    }.tint(.gray)
}
```

}

and this is what append why I scroll :

[tabbar disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvzhP.gif)

and on view with no scrollable object there is no background or a white background

[mapview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTwpp.png)

[chatview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRBns.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it with

```
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
tabBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
```

that's for translucent one